# PowerShell script - CommandLine of a process not showing

Tags: list, powershell, process, wmi

I've been trying to create a PowerShell script which should list all running instances of svchost.exe process along with their PID, CommandLine, CPU, and RAM usage. However, I have an issue with displaying CommandLine parameter - this line is blank for all the listed processes. Could you help me, please? (I'm only a beginner.)
Thanks!

```
Get-Process -Name svchost | 
Select-Object Id, ProcessName, CommandLine, @{Name='CPU Usage (%)';Expression={($_.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds / (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors)).ToString("F2")}}, 
@{Name='RAM Usage (MB)';Expression={[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet / 1MB),1)}} |
Out-File -FilePath "$env:userprofile\Desktop\svch_list.txt"
```

[image: List output]

Tried this code also but I couldn't get CPU usage to work properly - it was showing 0.00% for every listed process (CommandLine was working perfectly):

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE 'svchost%'" | 
Select-Object ProcessId, CommandLine, @{Name='CPU Usage';Expression={($_.PercentProcessorTime / (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors).ToString("P")}}, 
@{Name='RAM Usage (MB)';Expression={[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetSize / 1MB),1)}} |
Out-File -FilePath "$env:userprofile\Desktop\svch_list.txt"
```

[image: List output 2]

Comment: The [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0#properties) object doesn't have a `CommandLine` property....

Comment: @KeithMiller, it does in PowerShell 7+ (added as a ScriptProperty by PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

Your commands for obtaining the **command lines** are correct in principle:

- The first one only works in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), because only there are the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances output by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process)'s output *decorated* with a `.CommandLine` property *by PowerShell* (the linked type does *not* have this property); a simplified example:

  ```bash
  Get-Process svchost | Select-Object Id, Name, CommandLine
  ```
- The second one, based on [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) and the [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) class works in *Windows PowerShell* too; a simplified example (note the need to include `.exe` in this case, and the different column name for the process ID):

  ```bash
   Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "svchost.exe"' |
     Select-Object ProcessId, Name, CommandLine
  ```

However, to see *most* `svchost.exe` command lines, **you need to *run with elevation***, i.e. as an administrator (your second screenshot implies that you're already doing that).
(This isn't required to see the command lines of processes launched by *you* rather than the system).

However, even then  I see 2 processes that don't have a command line - not sure why.

---

As for calculating the **CPU utilization** in percent:

- **`.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds`** is the *cumulative* time that the given process has spent using the CPU(s) since it was launched. A such, it is ***not* suitable for calculating a *momentary* CPU utilization percentage**.
- While **`.PercentProcessorTime` *is* the correct property** for this calculation, it **only exists on the [`Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394323(v=vs.85)) WMI class**, not the `Win32_Process` class.

Therefore, a solution that works in *both* PowerShell editions is the following (`RAM Usage (MB)` column omitted):

```bash
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "svchost.exe"' |
   Select-Object ProcessId, Name, @{
                    Name = 'CPU Usage (%)'
                    Expression = {
                      ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "IDProcess = $($_.ProcessId)").PercentProcessorTime / $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).ToString('F2')
                    }
                  }, CommandLine
```

However, you can also use the [calculated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) `CPU Usage (%)` property with the PowerShell 7+ solution, if you replace `$_.ProcessId` with `$_.Id`.

Note:

- The `.PercentProcessorTime` value is an *integer* value, so its precision is limited, and it seemingly applies *across all logical processors* that the system has, so its value can be *greater* than `100`.
- Fractional values that may warrant `.ToString('F2')` formatting only come into play through the division by the number of logical processors (most easily obtained via the `$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` environment variable), which is necessary to normalize the value to a true percentage value (with a maximum of `100`).
- **Note that `svchost.exe` processes, specifically, often use so little CPU time that they show with `0%` CPU utilization** (confirm via Task Manager), so the fact that this value is reported for them does *not* mean that the calculation isn't working.

  - To verify that it *is* working, open a (separate) Windows PowerShell window and run a tight loop as follows in it: `while ($true) {}`
  - In a different PowerShell window, run the code above with `-Filter 'Name = "powershell.exe"'` instead of `-Filter 'Name = "svchost.exe"'`, and you should see a percentage value that close to  maxing out *one* of the logical processors in your system; e.g., if there are 2 logical processors, you should see a value close to `50%`.

Comment: I've tried this code:

Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "svchost.exe"' |
   Select-Object ProcessId, Name, @{
                    Name = 'CPU Usage (%)'
                    Expression = {
                      ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "IDProcess = $($_.ProcessId)").PercentProcessorTime / $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).ToString('F2')
                    }
                  }, CommandLine, @{Name='RAM Usage (MB)';Expression={[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetSize / 1MB),1)}} |
Out-File -FilePath "$env:userprofile\Desktop\svch_list.txt"

Comment: But CPU usage still shows 0.00% for every process. (I'm running the script under Windows 10's built-in Administrator account.)

Comment: @chrz997, that suggests that their CPU utilization is below 1 percent - you won't get more granular info than that with this method. If you want to verify that it works in principle, open a separate Windows PowerShell window, run `while ($true) { }` to create a tight loop, then run your command (in a different window) with  `-Filter 'Name = "powershell.exe"'` instead.