# PowerShell script CPU utilization of a process showing values above 100%

Tags: windows, list, powershell, process

I've been trying to create a PowerShell script which should list all running instances of svchost.exe process along with their PID, Path, CPU, and RAM utilization. However, I have an issue with displaying CPU usage parameter - it's showing values above 100%. Also, I need this script to work with PowerShell 4.0 installed. Could you help me, please?
Thanks.

```
$logicalProcessors = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$processes = Get-Process -Name svchost

$results = @()

foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $cpuUsage = [Math]::Ceiling(($process.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds / (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors)) * 100) / 100
    $ramUsage = [Math]::Round(($process.WorkingSet / 1MB), 2)

    $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "Id" = $process.Id
        "ProcessName" = $process.ProcessName
        "Path" = $process.Path
        "CPU Usage (%)" = $cpuUsage
        "RAM Usage (MB)" = $ramUsage
    }
}

$results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath "$env:userprofile\Desktop\svch_List.txt"
```

---

Output - svch_List.txt:

```
ProcessName Path                            RAM Usage (MB)    Id CPU Usage (%)
----------- ----                            --------------    -- -------------
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe          53,26   660         35,09
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           9,78   788           3,3
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe          19,23  1096         29,55
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           7,03  1152          5,15
svchost     C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe           4,47  1284          0,48
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           5,02  1464          0,39
svchost     C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe           5,16  1496          2,31
svchost     C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe           2,85  1512          0,39
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe            3,6  1544          1,32
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           3,47  1556          0,09
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           2,11  1580          0,02
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe           3,86  1592          0,15
svchost     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe          10,15  1600        150,58
```

Comment: To quote from my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75958279/45375):
`.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds` is the _cumulative_ time that the given process has spent using the CPU(s) _since it was launched_. A such, it is _not_ suitable for calculating a *momentary* CPU utilization percentage.

Comment: @mklement0
Thanks. Could you, please, provide me with more details about what should I use instead? Like I mentioned in the post - this code needs to run under PowerShell 4.0. Thank you.

Comment: Unless you need sub-percentage-point granularity, I would expect the linked answer to work in v4.0 too. Note that `svchost` processes are often all at `0%` (confirm via Task Manager).